# End to end testing error (Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.)

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

I have test my controller using End 2 End testing when i execute the following code

```
it('should successfully login and create a session using valid credentials', function() {
        //browser.get('http://localhost:5000/' + '#/login');
        element(by.model('username'));
        element(by.model('password'));
        element(by.id('btnLogin')).click();
        expect(browser.getLocationAbsUrl()).not.toMatch("/login");
    });
```

it ll show **error** like as below

> Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.

how can i solve this error.. please help any one.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but isn't it protractor not karma?

Comment: sorry its protractor

Comment: Is the issue resolved?If yes, please post the solution.